# Change subscriber connection on SQL Server Replication Subscription through .net

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, replication

I've got a block of .net code which creates replication subscriptions between two SQL Server 2008 instances. Mostly it works fine, but whenever it's run it sets the "subscriber connection" property to "Impersonate Windows Account". This works locally but it isn't what we need in the live environment at all - it needs to be a SQL server logon. However I can't find the correct propert/method/syntax (or anything really) in the SqlServer.Replication.TransSubscription class to change it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Am I even looking in the correct class to control this programatically?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell without seeing any code, but is the [ConnectionSecurityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.connectionsecuritycontext.aspx) what you need to change this setting?